# New files in Zend Framework 2 Skeleton Application

Tags: javascript, css, zend-framework2

I've downloaded the Zend Framework 2 skeleton application and modified the standard `layout.phtml` and other files to my own layout, but the javascript and stylesheet files seem not to be found, although I can see them in the code inspector.

I like to use Aptana Studio 3, and every new file has a red background and a small `?` on their icon in the files tree.

I'd appreciate any help and suggestion.

Comment: <?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/path/to/js/some.js

Comment: I don't understand. The layout.phtml file has few javascript files called, and I copy the `->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/lightbox.min.js')` but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: <script src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/path/to/some.js" type="text/javascript">></script>. Basically this should work. If the js folder is inside the public folder then this should work

Comment: Great, worked perfectly now, but I would like to understand why using their own way to call for a JavaScript file did not work.

Comment: Check the prependFile metgod maybe it will clear thinga out